# R - Why am I getting an error message in a shiny server?

Tags: r, ubuntu, server, shiny

I'm currently usinga shiny server using DigitalOcean with Ubuntu as the operating system. I created a survey with the hopes of collecting user inputs and writing them in a csv file.

Locally, it works (i.e. responses get saved in a local folder). However, when I developed a shiny app within my new R Studio server to test it, there is an error which reads:

```
"Error: cannot open the connection"
```

This occurs when I press the submit button. I think the error occurs because my shiny server doesn't have rights to save files in my desired folder, i.e.

```
 /home/my_user/test
```

The folder I'd save the responses would be located in that shiny folder in my new R Studio directory.

I've checked extensively on the website and I found:

[Write permission from shiny app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36676109/write-permission-from-shiny-app)

[Permission denied while using write.csv on ubuntu server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48961553/permission-denied-while-using-write-csv-on-ubuntu-server)

This is my saveData function:

```
saveData <- function(data) {

  fileName <- sprintf("%s_%s.csv", humanTime(), digest::digest(data))
  write.csv(x = data, file = file.path(responsesDir, fileName), row.names = FALSE, quote = TRUE)
}
```

The response directory (responsesDir) is

```
/home/my_user/test/csv_files
```

I've tried the following:

```
sudo chown shiny:shiny /var/shiny-server/test/
```

It says that there is no such file or directory.

Am I missing something very obvious? Thank you so much!